# cookies with the same name don't show up in curl nor in apache http client

Tags: curl, cookies, apache-httpclient-4.x, androidhttpclient

I am trying to save log in cookies from a website. after I make a POST request I recieve cookies. here are the list of cookies in google chrome[image]

but when I use curl

> curl -D - --data "somedata=value" url -o file.html

I only get the first occuranc of every duplicate cookie

```
> Set-Cookie: khamsat0=; max-age=0; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 -0000
Set-Cookie: khamsat1=; max-age=0; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 -0000
Set-Cookie: khamsat2=; max-age=0; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 -0000
Set-Cookie: khamsat3=; max-age=0; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 -0000
Set-Cookie: rack.session=BAh7CUkiD3Nlc3Npb25faWQGOgZFVEkiRWUwMzc1YmM4YjBlMWQwZDYxOTNi%0AMDRjOTFlYTc4MWEwZjAyNTJhODAzNmRmMmVlMWU2NmUzY2Y5Y2M5Mzk5ZmMG%0AOwBGSSIJY3NyZgY7AEZJIiVlZDlkZGQ2YWJkODNjZTU0OGVhNjJkMmQxYzhk%0AMDE5ZgY7AEZJIg10cmFja2luZwY7AEZ7B0kiFEhUVFBfVVNFUl9BR0VOVAY7%0AAFRJIi1kOGY0NzliOWNjMDQ1MTg1ZjBiNmUzOThkMGVlMGQwYTI0ZDM4ZDUy%0ABjsARkkiGUhUVFBfQUNDRVBUX0xBTkdVQUdFBjsAVEkiLWRhMzlhM2VlNWU2%0AYjRiMGQzMjU1YmZlZjk1NjAxODkwYWZkODA3MDkGOwBGSSIPY3NyZi50b2tl%0AbgY7AFRJIjFaUmJodTRuVTR2WkRsRWtPNWFsUEVZc3FldlE4QTU4aUZ1bjFN%0AcFVsS1pvPQY7AEY%3D%0A--c7e0e2d2cbf025f608d5c76e0f7b58ef602bca3c; path=/; HttpOnly
```

the same for [Apache DefaultHttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.html)

the question is: How do I get the messing cookies ?

Answer (score 2):

If you get different headers returned when you use curl vs when you use Chrome, that is *probably* because the site simply acts differently depending on which user-agent it detects.

You can try to set a more Chrome-looking user-agent with curl and otherwise try to mimic Chrome closer and it may make a difference.

But, a browser can also for example set cookies with javascript etc which curl doesn't support so it isn't necessarily sure that you can get the exact same set of cookies.

Comment: so,  the web view was able to get the cookies correctly